# Speed up reading HTTP response body for speed test

Tags: http, go, io, buffer

I'm writing a (hopefully zero-dependency) speed test in Go leveraging Netflix's fast.com servers.

The code is pulling down several pieces of 25MB content, reading the response into a buffer and counting the bytes read along the way.

The code (speed test) works as expected on my development computer, but **when I run it on a much tinier linux machine, the speed test caps out at measuring ~75Mbps** (despite being hardwired into a network reliably providing 400+Mbps).

I believe the issue must be that because the machine is small, it's relatively slow at either reading the response or writing into the buffer.

I did a Go trace of the program on the 2 machines, and sure enough the Heap on the small linux machine continually gets full before GC clears it out; rinse and repeat.

The question is: what can I do about this to make my speed test accurate? More specifically, since I don't actually need the response data (because this is just a speed test), is there a way I can download and count the bytes from the HTTP response without actually bothering to write them anywhere, thus potentially saving time?

The relevant code is below. (Note: the reason I'm using http.NewRequest is because in some cases I build on URL params).

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
defer resp.Body.Close()
buffer := make([]byte, 128 * 1024)
for {
    b, err := resp.Body.Read(buffer)
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    func() {
        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()

        *bytesRead += b
        if *done {
            return
        }
    }()
}
```

Edit: I should also add that the linux device has been tested and validated via other speed tests that it can achieve greater than 75Mbps.

Comment: You are allocating only one buffer. There is no reason for the memory to get full. Do you have multiple goroutines running this test? Based on the mutex at the end, I suppose there is. You can use `sync/atomic` to add to the `bytesRead`, reducing the lock overhead.

Comment: Handling network packets is not free, a constrained system can easily be CPU limited to ~75Mbps regardless of the hardwired connection.

Comment: @BurakSerdar yes there are 5 CDN endpoints and therefore 5 Goroutines running the function above. I'm new to Go: if I use `sync/atomic`, then do I get rid of `mu.Lock()` and `mu.Unlock()`?

Comment: Yes, you can get rid of the mutex. However, that will be negligible compared to the network operations. You might try increasing the buffer size and increasing the OS network buffer size.

Comment: @JimB I'm able to record TCP throughput at 300+Mbps via other speed tests.

Comment: The need for synchronization indicates there is something you're not showing us. What are you doing that is causing the allocations? Get the total bytes with `io.Copy(io.Discard, resp.Body)` and see if that makes any difference

Comment: @BurakSerdar unfortunately using `atomic/sync` to add to total bytes seemed to have no meaningful effect.

Comment: @JimB my main() function first gets the CDN urls for the speed test, then for each of those urls, it spins up a goroutine calling the function I have shared, passing the `bytesRead *int` location.

Then I start a 1 second ticker, checking how many bytes were written each second, and resetting the value to 0 afterward so I can take the max bytes recorded in any second-long interval during the test.

I tried your suggestion of using `io.Copy` but it results in most of my ticker's second intervals showing no bytes downloaded.

Comment: yes, the idea with `io.Copy` is to remove as much of your code as possible to try and locate the bottleneck. You need to calculate the total bytes and speed rather than second-by-second to see if that has any merit.

Comment: Could you share the full program? Current code snippet lacks detail.

Comment: @JimB `io.Discard` isn't solving the problem. Roughly same throughput.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `io.Discard` Writer in order to speedup the code, an example:

```golang
var bytesRead int64
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
nBytes, err := io.Copy(io.Discard, resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
bytesRead += nBytes
```

By this way you don't need to iterate among a bytes buffer.